# Proof of converse of Menelaus's Theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am not understanding completely the last affermation of the following proof of the converse of Menelaus's Theorem.

In the detail, the author, after having proven in general Menelaus's Theorem for general points $X,Y$ and $Z$ (which lie respectively on sides $BC,CA$ and $AB$, which are extended if necessary), he now proves its converse as follows: (the proof is from AOPS II book)

> Moving to our proof, we will show that $YZ,BC$ intersect at the point X
>   which satisfies Menelaus's Theorem. Let this intersection point be
>   $X'$, where $X$ is a point on $BC$ that, along with $Y$ and $Z$ on $AC$
>   and $AB$ respectively, satisfies $$ \frac {BX \cdot CY \cdot AZ}{ CX \cdot AY \cdot BZ}=1    \tag 1$$
>
> Since $Y$ and $Z$ are on $AC$ and $AB$, and $X'$ is on both $YZ $ and
>   $BC$, we also have: $$\frac{BX' \cdot CY \cdot AZ}{CX' \cdot AY \cdot
>  BZ}=1$$
>
> Combining these we find $$\frac{BX}{CX}=\frac{BX'}{CX'} $$
>
> If these ratios both equal $1$, then we are done, since the above
>   equality will then imply that $X$ and $X'$ are both the midpoint of
>   $BC$. If the costand ratio is not $1$, then we have another problem.
>   (...)

My question is about why the last affermation is true.What are the cases where,given that $\cfrac{BX}{CX}=c$ where $c \ne 1$ and $c \gt 0$, we have multiple points $X'$ on $BC$ such that $\cfrac{BX'}{CX'}=c$ ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if we don't specify whether $X$ is inside or outside interval $\overline{BC}$. If we take two points $X_1,X_2$ such that $X_2$ is between $B,C$ and $B$ is between $X_1,C$ such that $X_1B=BC,X_2B=BC/3$ then we have $X_1C/X_1B=2=X_2C/X_2B$.

[image]

Comment: Okay now i see what they mean,but how can we have two  points on $BC$ given that if we extend $YZ$ we will have only one intersection pointwith $BC$(inside or outside the interval)?This looks a bit of a contradiction to me ..can you clear this to me ?Thanks for your answer(i was looking disperately for one).

Comment: @Nameless The problem is, the converse of Menelaus theorem isn't simply "if (the ratio in question)=1 then the three points are colinear". We need further conditions. Usually these conditions are stated as "either none of the points $X,Y,Z$, or exactly two of them, lie inside the respective line segments". This is why we exclude one of these points.

Comment: Ahh ! that's why we use the notion of directed segments to have only one point of intersection ?Hence can we prove the converse given that $X$ is the point intercepted by the directed segment $Y,Z$ ?

Comment: @Nameless I'm not sure I understand. I think you are talking about a part of the proof outside the fragment quoted in the question body.

Comment: I was trying to say that if we use the notion of directed segment where $YZ=-ZY$ depending on the direction of the line extended from the segment ,then i thought that we had solved the problem of having multiple points of intersection with $BC$.

Comment: @Nameless Indeed, I am fairly sure it does fix the problem.

Comment: Indeed there was a slight typo; corrected now.

Comment: No, I actually do mean $X_2B=BC/3$, as then $X_2C=2BC/3$ and $X_2C/X_2B=2$.

Comment: I never said it is.

Comment: I mean that $X_2$ is inside the interval $BC$. I haven't said it is supposed to be halfway between the points.